# MR Job from Java action run locally from Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm trying to run a sequence of MR jobs using Java action for their drivers in Oozie.

The problem is that MR job are run locally instead on Hadoop cluster. How to fix this?

Here is what the configuration looks like when I create it using default constructor

`Configuration conf = new Configuration()`

```
mapreduce.jobtracker.address = local
mapreduce.framework.name = local
```

I was able to make my MR job run on HDP cluster by adding this to configuration (based on the following link):

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration(false);
conf.addResource(new Path("file:///", System.getProperty("oozie.action.conf.xml")));
```

And then when I print the conf it looks like:

```
mapreduce.jobtracker.address = 192.168.84.27:8050
mapreduce.framework.name = yarn
```

But why do I need to do that and how to avoid it? I have a sequence of MR jobs run from this Java action and I don't want to bind myself to using Oozie and adding this to config of each job. Is there a way to make my jobs run on cluster from Oozie by default?

I should probably mention that this is an HDP cluster and setup was performed through Ambari.

Comment: Open the YARN logs for the Oozie "launcher" container, and look specifically for CLASSPATH. It should contain the local dir where the local Hadoop config files have been created by Ambari, typically `/etc/hadoop/conf` -- yes, it's a directory, and it's in the CLASSPATH, and that's how the `Configuration` constructor is supposed to find the appropriate `***-site.xml` conf files.

Comment: If the container CLASSPATH is screwed up, you should yell at your Hadoop admin. Or, as a quick-and-dirty fix, you can use `addresource()` for all Hadoop conf that your code requires i.e. for MR  `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Well, it contains only /etc/hadoop/conf/secure, I'm guessing that's not good? But what could be the concrete problem that causes this? As it is a HDP cluster all was installed automatically, including Oozie.

Comment: I have a feeling that you had quite an experience with this "feature"? :) Where should I add the symlinks?

Comment: If the Oozie job expects to find the XML files in the `secure` subdir, just create symlinks there, e.g. `mkdir /etc/hadoop/conf/secure/ ; ln -s /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml /etc/hadoop/conf/secure/core-site.xml`

Comment: I am not sure I like this approach - symlinking/copying configs. You risk running with stale configs at some point. This path comes from mapreduce.application.classpath property value. I just had to deal with the very same problem  - using existing Java "driver" app that launches MR job. I wanted to Oozie'fy it. Long story short, I had to add "/etc/hadoop/conf" to the end of mapreduce.application.classpath to solve this problem. And I absolutely had to restart both Yarn and Oozie for the change to take effect. Works now, java action starts separate MR job and waits for completion.